# Python replace class object.variable with value in place

Tags: python

I am thinking is there any way to replace a object.variable with value in place for class object.

For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.attr1 = a

a_obj1 = A('Name1')
print(a_obj1.attr1)
```

> Prints Name1

And if I keep the attr1 in a variable, and try to access it, then it

```
a_obj2 = A('Name2')
attrName = 'attr1'
print(a_obj2.attrName)
```

> Shows AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'attrName'

My understanding is that the REPL parser of python probably not expanding any thing after **.** which makes sense. 
But is there any way to achieve this? In particular combine a varaible's value with another variable to make a variable?

Update: Thanks [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093741/chris) . Found the solution.

Comment: You need `getattr`: try `getattr(a_obj2, attrName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.attr1 = a

a_obj1 = A('Name1')
print(a_obj1.attr1)
a_obj2 = A('Name2')
attrName = 'attr1'
print(getattr(a_obj2, attrName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr()` with the format `gettattr(a_obj, attrName)`